# Can only edit list forms with InfoPath

Tags: list-form

I've got an issue in SharePoint 2010 where I can only edit list forms with InfoPath.  Any idea how to restore default form editing for a given site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for both SharePoint 2010 and 2013.

Go to the list where you wanna get rid of the custom InfoPath forms, go to a list/library settings > Form Settings > Select "Use the default SharePoint form" and if you like to get rid of the customized forms, check the box for deleting the forms from the server.

[image]

Comment: My issue is that, after doing the above, i cannot edit the default form.  I'm given the option of customizing the form in InfoPath, but I cannot edit it in SP.

Comment: The above restores the forms to the default, and now you wanna edit them but not by using InfoPath?

Comment: What would you like to do?

Comment: That's correct.  I'd like to use the default form editor, but it's not listed as an option.  If i delete the infopath form, I'm still redirected to info path if i try to customize the form.  It's like default form editing is gone

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by default form editing.. Do you mean SharePoint Designer by any means? https://support.content.office.net/en-US/media/12315d44-3090-475b-a20d-c9baf5fe1be5.jpg

Comment: In referring to the ability to add, move, and remove form tabs and field directly through the browser in SharePoint.

Comment: http://blog.pentalogic.net/2010/07/how-to-edit-list-forms-sharepoint-2010/